# Error using scrollTo on recycler view espresso android testing

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my android instrumentation tests I am trying to tap on a recycler view that is off the page view. I want to scroll to this element and then tap it.

I have written the code

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.offerSummaryLayout), hasDescendant(withText("Online deal")), FirstViewMatcher.firstView())).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

However when I do this it throws this error
`android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: uk.co.myAPP.android.beta:id/offerSummaryLayout and has descendant: with text: is "Online sale" and  is the first view that comes along )
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.GridView{3395c7d VFED.VC.. .F...... 0,120-768,700 #7f1000b9 app:id/main_categories_grid_view}`

Has anyone else expereinced this issue or have an resolutions I can use

Comment: Make use of [RecyclerViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html).

Comment: the item you want to click is not visible, so you may want to do something like : onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).perform(scrollToPosition(position));

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If not then please remove the "coded-ui-tests" tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom matcher:

```
private <View> Matcher<View> first(final Matcher<View> matcher) {
    return new BaseMatcher<View>() {
        boolean isFirst = true;

        @Override
        public boolean matches(final Object item) {
            if (isFirst && matcher.matches(item)) {
                isFirst = false;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("should return first matching item");
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use it as `OnView(allOf(withId(R.id.offerSummaryLayout)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(first(hasDescendant(withText("Online deal"))),click()));`

Comment: This will pick all of them matching this I need to tap only the first one it finds

Comment: Have edited your answer to - `onView(allOf(withId(R.id.offerSummaryLayout))).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(Matchers.allOf(hasDescendant(withText("Online sale"))),click()));`

Comment: It has helped but would you be able to help me change it to the first found instead of all please

Comment: @BillyBoyo You can write a custom matcher to check for the first matching item only.